# PHP Regex to match a specific css class name + :before pseudo

Tags: php, css, regex

Been more than 6 hours trying to find best PHP regex to match a specific class name + :before pseudo. For example I have css code like this

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.65em;
}

p{line-height: 1.5em; margin: 10px 0;}

.action-admin:before{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.action-user:before{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}

footer{
   clear: both;
}
```

so, I want to search all css code that have class name match with **'.action-{anyotherwords}:before'** and listed them in a php variable (will process this to next action)

so, in simple words - I only want to get these code below from my css above

```
.action-admin:before{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.action-user:before{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to find all these blocks:

```
\.action-[\w-]+:before\s*?\{[^}]+\}
```

[image]

Example:

```
preg_match_all("/\.action-[\w-]+:before\s*?\{[^}]+\}/", $css, $matches);
$actionCSS = implode("\n\n", $matches[0]);
```

The CSS code with only the action blocks will then be in `$actionCSS`.

Comment: RegEx should be `\.action-[a-z]+:before\s*\{[^}]+\}`. Keep in mind this only allows for lowercase letters after ".action".

Comment: @tenub True, I limited myself to the bare minimum for his example code, but yours is better for generic CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me how to allow uppercase, number and another "-" too after ".action-" , I have some class with number, Uppercase and double "-", e.g. "action-super-admin{" , "action-Model-Cat1{" - Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Omar I've updated the regex to match everything after action, including dashes and uppercase characters (this will also match invalid CSS).

Comment: I would only allow numbers, uppercase characters, underscores, and hyphens (which are the only valid css characters that might appear here). Just change `[a-z]` to `[\w-]`. `[^:]` means anything other than a ":" which could include things like "–" or "÷".

Comment: @Omar As tenub says, the new regex is better if you only want to match valid CSS.